# FSharp build succeeded but no dll files in Debug folder

Tags: .net, docker, build, f#, .net-framework-version

My solution has 5 projects and they build using msbuild locally, all projects are in F# and are net48.

My msbuild version locally is:
17.6.3.22601
The msbuild version on docker container mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 is:
17.7.2.37605

I essentially get no warnings when I built in docker container and also no get no dlls. The behaviour is different on local where I get warnings and dlls.

I have tried reinstalling F# compiler on the docker container using paket but that did not solve the issue.
I have the following F# compiler on docker.
12.7.0.0 for F# 7
Following is locally:
12.5.0.0 for F# 7

Following is from a boiler plate F# .net 48 application:

```
C:\src\ConsoleApplication2>msbuild ConsoleApplication2.sln /verbosity:d
MSBuild version 17.7.2+d6990bcfa for .NET Framework
Build started 8/28/2023 1:38:46 PM.
Process = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"
MSBuild executable path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"
Command line arguments = "msbuild  ConsoleApplication2.sln /verbosity:d"
Current directory = "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2"
MSBuild version = "17.7.2+d6990bcfa"
Some command line switches were read from the auto-response file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.rsp". To disable this file, use the "-noAutoR
esponse" switch.

Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Trying to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\* using extensions path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2
022\BuildTools\MSBuild
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: Microsoft.IO.Redist, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Curr
ent\Bin\Microsoft.IO.Redist.dll, MVID: d528d43e-4d35-4c28-8aa6-a5ce49a5eba7, AppDomain: [Default])
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\B
in\System.Buffers.dll, MVID: f389ca43-32bf-4e24-ad8c-a6ed5efddff3, AppDomain: [Default])
Property reassignment: $(_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntryInputProperties)="
      ExcludeRestorePackageImports=true;
      _RestoreSolutionFileUsed=true;
      SolutionDir=C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\;
      SolutionName=ConsoleApplication2;
      SolutionFileName=ConsoleApplication2.sln;
      SolutionPath=C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln;
      SolutionExt=.sln;
    " (previous value: "ExcludeRestorePackageImports=true") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.targets (86,5)
The target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.
targets (602,11)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
Project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
Target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" in file "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln.metaproj" from project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" (entry point):
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; (('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' == '') and ('$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' != 'true')) was evaluated as (('<SolutionConfiguration>
  <ProjectConfiguration Project="{3EE67E9D-EFFE-4767-95BC-0D5502DD1502}" AbsolutePath="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Debug|AnyCPU</ProjectConfiguration>
</SolutionConfiguration>' == '') and ('' != 'true')).
Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; (('$(CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents)' == '') and ('$(SkipInvalidConfigurations)' == 'true')) was evaluated as (('<SolutionConfiguration>
  <ProjectConfiguration Project="{3EE67E9D-EFFE-4767-95BC-0D5502DD1502}" AbsolutePath="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Debug|AnyCPU</ProjectConfiguration>
</SolutionConfiguration>' == '') and ('' == 'true')).
Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "Message"
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Done executing task "Message".
Done building target "ValidateSolutionConfiguration" in project "ConsoleApplication2.sln".
Target "ValidateToolsVersions" in file "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln.metaproj" from project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" (entry point):
Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(MSBuildToolsVersion)' == '2.0' and ('$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '2.0' and '$(ProjectToolsVersion)' != '')) was evaluated as ('Current' == '2.0' and ('' != '2.
0' and '' != '')).
Done building target "ValidateToolsVersions" in project "ConsoleApplication2.sln".
Target "ValidateProjects" in file "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln.metaproj" from project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" (entry point):
Done building target "ValidateProjects" in project "ConsoleApplication2.sln".
Target "Build" in file "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln.metaproj" from project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" (entry point):
Using "MSBuild" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
Task "MSBuild"
  Global Properties:
    BuildingSolutionFile=true
    CurrentSolutionConfigurationContents=<SolutionConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Project="{3EE67E9D-EFFE-4767-95BC-0D5502DD1502}" AbsolutePath="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj" BuildProjectInSolution="True">Debug|AnyCPU</ProjectConfiguration
  >
  </SolutionConfiguration>
    SolutionDir=C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\
    SolutionExt=.sln
    SolutionFileName=ConsoleApplication2.sln
    SolutionName=ConsoleApplication2
    SolutionPath=C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln
  Additional Properties for project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj":
    Configuration=Debug
    Platform=AnyCPU
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver, Version=6.7.0.127, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildToo
ls\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll, MVID: 940c702f-fb85-47ce-9fef-5f342e7c855c, AppDomain: [Default])
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver, Version=7.0.400.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Build
Tools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver\Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver.dll, MVID: 96f8a957-5d83-4e2c-a0f3-2536e547da2c, AppDomain: [Default])
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: Microsoft.Deployment.DotNet.Releases, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildT
ools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver\Microsoft.Deployment.DotNet.Releases.dll, MVID: 335cdaa7-b3c2-440d-acfd-ed76d88c2cd6, AppDomain: [Default])
Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk'...
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current
\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.DotNet.MSBuildSdkResolver\Newtonsoft.Json.dll, MVID: f7499511-9334-484f-b6db-6825be2eac0d, AppDomain: [Default])
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Trying to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props using extensions path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\
BuildTools\MSBuild
Property reassignment: $(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\" (previous value: "obj\") at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.Co
mmon.props (60,5)
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Trying to import C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Imports\Microsoft.Common.props\ImportBefore\* using extensions path C:\Program Files (x86)\Micros
oft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild
The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
The "Platform" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
Search paths being used for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) are C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild;$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\MSBuild
The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
The "Platform" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
Property reassignment: $(AssemblySearchPaths)="{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem}" (previous value: "{CandidateAssemblyFiles}") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\M
icrosoft.NET.Sdk.props (82,5)
Property reassignment: $(AssemblySearchPaths)="{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory}" (previous value: "{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem}") at C:\Program Files\dotne
t\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props (83,5)
Property reassignment: $(AssemblySearchPaths)="{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFrameworkDirectory};{RawFileName}" (previous value: "{CandidateAssemblyFiles};{HintPathFromItem};{TargetFramew
orkDirectory}") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props (84,5)
Property reassignment: $(PublishAotSupported)="true" (previous value: "false") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.props (120,5)
Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadAutoImportPropsLocator'...
Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler'...
Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks'...
Property reassignment: $(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage)=";PackTool;_PackProjectToolValidation" (previous value: ";PackTool") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Micro
soft.NET.PackProjectTool.props (15,5)
Property reassignment: $(OutputType)="Exe" (previous value: "Library") at C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj (3,5)
The "Configuration" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
The "Platform" property is a global property, and cannot be modified.
Property reassignment: $(PublishProfileImported)="false" (previous value: "true") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportPublishProfile.targets (28,5)
Assembly loaded during Evaluation: NuGet.Frameworks, Version=6.7.0.127, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 (location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\C
ommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\NuGet.Frameworks.dll, MVID: f81f92ce-f098-4129-8a9b-9a6f878460a1, AppDomain: [Default])
Property reassignment: $(TargetPlatformVersion)="" (previous value: "0.0") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (65,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFramew
orkInference.targets (247,5)
Property reassignment: $(IntermediateOutputPath)="obj\Debug\net48\" (previous value: "obj\Debug\") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.
targets (266,5)
Property reassignment: $(OutputPath)="bin\Debug\net48\" (previous value: "bin\Debug\") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (267
,5)
Resolving SDK 'Microsoft.NET.SDK.WorkloadManifestTargetsLocator'...
Property reassignment: $(_FrameworkIdentifierForImplicitDefine)="NET" (previous value: "NETFRAMEWORK") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targ
ets (182,5)
Property reassignment: $(_FrameworkVersionForImplicitDefine)="4_8" (previous value: "4.8") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (185,5)
Property reassignment: $(_FrameworkVersionForImplicitDefine)="48" (previous value: "4_8") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BeforeCommon.targets (186,5)
Property reassignment: $(ProjectAssetsFile)="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\project.assets.json" (previous value: "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\/project.assets.json") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\
Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets (24,5)
Property reassignment: $(ProjectAssetsCacheFile)="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.assets.cache" (previous value: "obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.assets.cache") at C:\Progra
m Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets (29,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Micr
osoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (27,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.
Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (29,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\S
dks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (32,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user") at C:\Program Files
\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (33,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj;**/*.sln" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj")
 at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (34,5)
Property reassignment: $(DefaultItemExcludes)=";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user;**/*.*proj;**/*.sln;**/*.vssscc" (previous value: ";bin\Debug\/**;obj\Debug\/**;bin\/**;obj\/**;**/*.user;
**/*.*proj;**/*.sln") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets (35,5)
Property reassignment: $(ResolveAssemblyReferencesDependsOn)="

      ;
      ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild;
      _HandlePackageFileConflicts;
    ;
      ResolveTargetingPackAssets;
    " (previous value: "
      ;
      ResolvePackageDependenciesForBuild;
      _HandlePackageFileConflicts;
    ") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets (14,5)
Property reassignment: $(_GenerateRuntimeConfigurationPropertyInputsCache)="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.genruntimeconfig.cache" (previous value: "obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleAppl
ication2.genruntimeconfig.cache") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (44,5)
Property 'USERPROFILE' with value 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator' expanded from the environment.
Property reassignment: $(_DefaultUserProfileRuntimeStorePath)="C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.tar
gets (77,5)
Property reassignment: $(_DefaultUserProfileRuntimeStorePath)="C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\.dotnet\store" (previous value: "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Mi
crosoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (78,5)
Property reassignment: $(DesignerRuntimeImplementationProjectOutputGroupDependsOn)="

      ;
    ;
      _GenerateDesignerDepsFile;
      _GenerateDesignerRuntimeConfigFile;
      GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems;
      _GatherDesignerShadowCopyFiles;
    " (previous value: "
      ;
    ") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.DesignerSupport.targets (21,5)
Property reassignment: $(_ShimInputCacheFile)="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.shiminput.cache" (previous value: "obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.shiminput.cache") at C:\Pro
gram Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.PackTool.targets (115,5)
Property reassignment: $(_ShimCreatedSentinelFile)="C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.shimcreated.sentinel" (previous value: "obj\Debug\net48\ConsoleApplication2.shimcreated.senti
nel") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.PackTool.targets (117,5)
Property reassignment: $(PackageDescription)="Package Description" (previous value: "") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (34,5)
Property reassignment: $(GenerateNuspecDependsOn)="Build;_LoadPackInputItems; _GetTargetFrameworksOutput; _WalkEachTargetPerFramework; _GetPackageFiles; " (previous value: "_LoadPackInputItems; _GetTargetFram
eworksOutput; _WalkEachTargetPerFramework; _GetPackageFiles; ") at C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (59,5)
Overriding target "_CheckBrowserWorkloadNeededButNotAvailable" in project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net6\WorkloadManifest.targets" with target "_Chec
kBrowserWorkloadNeededButNotAvailable" from project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net7\WorkloadManifest.targets".
Overriding target "_ErrorDisabledWorkload" in project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net6\WorkloadManifest.targets" with target "_ErrorDisabledWorkload" f
rom project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\7.0.100\microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain.net7\WorkloadManifest.targets".
Overriding target "ResolveReadyToRunCompilers" in project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.CrossGen.targets" with target "ResolveReadyToRunCompilers" from proj
ect "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets".
The target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets
(89,11)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "GetFrameworkPaths" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (89,11)" does not exist
 in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (89,11)" does n
ot exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "Restore" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (89,11)" does not exist in the pr
oject, and will be ignored.
The target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets
(105,11)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "GetFrameworkPaths" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets (105,11)" does not exis
t in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program 

The target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (192,11)" does not exist in the pro
ject, and will be ignored.
The target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (286,11)" does not exist in the pro
ject, and will be ignored.
The target "BuiltProjectOutputGroup" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (337,11)" does not exist in the projec
t, and will be ignored.
The target "GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (346,11)" does not exist in the
project, and will be ignored.
The target "_GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItemsFromThisProject" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (346,11)" does n
ot exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "AssignTargetPaths" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (762,11)" does not exist in the project, and
 will be ignored.
The target "PreBuildEvent" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (1043,11)" does not exist in the project, and wi
ll be ignored.
The target "_GetProjectReferenceTargetFrameworkProperties" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (1135,11)" does
not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets (1154,11)" does not e
xist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "BeforeCompile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets (54,11)" does not exist in the
project, and will be ignored.
The target "CoreCompile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets (54,11)" does not exist in the pr
oject, and will be ignored.
The target "GenerateBindingRedirects" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.GenerateSupportedRuntime.targets (24,11)" does no
t exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "_GenerateProjectRestoreGraphPerFramework" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ComposeStore.targets (445,11)" do
es not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "CollectPackageReferences" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.ObsoleteReferences.targets (27,11)" does not exis
t in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.PackTool.targets (122,11)" does not exist in th
e project, and will be ignored.
The target "CopyFilesToOutputDirectory" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.PreserveCompilationContext.targets (85,11)" doe
s not exist in the project, and will be ignored.
The target "Build" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (163,11)" does not exist in the project, and wil
l be ignored.
The target "Clean" listed in an AfterTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets (170,11)" does not exist in the project, and wil
l be ignored.
Project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" (1) is building "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
Target "_CheckForUnsupportedTargetFramework" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_UnsupportedTargetFrameworkError)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true').
Target "_CollectTargetFrameworkForTelemetry" in file "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets" from project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication
2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj" (entry point):
Using "AllowEmptyTelemetry" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\..\tools\net472\Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.dll".
Task "AllowEmptyTelemetry"
Done executing task "AllowEmptyTelemetry".
Done building target "_CollectTargetFrameworkForTelemetry" in project "ConsoleApplication2.fsproj".
Done Building Project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.fsproj" (default targets).

Done executing task "MSBuild".
Done building target "Build" in project "ConsoleApplication2.sln".
Done Building Project "C:\src\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2.sln" (default targets).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.88
```

Comment: This is cumbersome to read. Learn to format your post with texts instead of linking to external images of simple text. When you do have images with interesting content in the future, then put them directly in the post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: HI, I have edited my post to have some logs from a boiler plate F# .net 48 console application. 

Essentially I am trying to msbuild Consoleapp.sln inside mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 but I get no dlls